# Is it possible to copy and paste a gradient fill color in Adobe Fireworks?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-fireworks

I've got a series of button graphics that need to have the same gradient fill color.  I'm a Photoshop guy, so I'm in uncharted territory here.

Comment: This question just got bumped by the Community user because it didn't have an accepted answer. If you accept your own answer it will be ignored in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, that was quick.  I finally figured out that you can create a new "Style" in the Styles palette with the properties you want (fill, stroke, etc.).  Then you just click on the item you want to have that style, and then click the style.

Answer (score 1):

You know you can copy effects by Copy (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and Paste Atrributes (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>). 
If you do the same with the **sub-selection tool** - it will copy the gradient.